# When I upload my html file via filezilla to server é gets converted to Ã©. Why? Solution?

Tags: html, character-encoding, filezilla

Example: http://users.hogent.be/subedi/htm/nl/bio.htm 1st paragraph, third line.

If I view this file before uploading I see correct characters. I get correct characters if I download and view this file with filezilla as well. Its uploaded to my schools's server.

How can I display those characters correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding is being guessed at incorrectly by the browser.

You can fix this on your browser by telling it to use unicode/utf-8.

But in order to fix this for every visitor you should put a meta tag into your html that will tell user-agents to [use utf8](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.en).

`<meta charset="utf-8"/>`

Comment: I corrected my meta-tag. Character is still not displayed correctly.

Comment: Server was sending incorrect HTTP content type. Setting meta tag had no point. I changed my document's encoding to more obscure ISO-8859-1 instead.

Comment: I think you might have to put quotes around the utf-8 as in `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Also according to the W3.org site it should be the first thing after opening the `<head>` tag

Comment: From the page you linked: Note however that, since the HTTP header has a higher precedence than the in-document meta declarations, content authors should always take into account whether the character encoding is already declared in the HTTP header.Server is sending ISO-8859-1 so I have to use ISO-8859-1 as well in my html file. I did tried using quotes, it didn't helped.

Comment: You're right. Looks like the server is sending the encoding in the header. `Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` So you'll have to configure the server differently or encode the html files in ISO-8859-1 like you're doing.